# Open link in new tab using Ctrl+Click on ButtonLink

Tags: .net

I am trying to open the link (created using LinkButton) in the new window using Ctrl+Click, but the page is opening in the same window.

But here is some condition:
1. When I simply click (mouse click) on the link, it should open in the same tab.

2. When I click (Ctrl+Click) on the link, it should open in the new tab

Please help me with the solution.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtnAdd_Click">Add New</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lnkbtnAdd" runat="server" onClientClick="window.open('http://stackoverflow.com');" ...
```

**EDIT:** Based on your newer update, you need to use javascript to alter the behavior. You can help yourself with some javascript library, such as jQuery or so.